# How $\det(AB)=\det(A)\cdot \det(B)$, when $A, B$ not square matrixes but $AB$ square

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a matrix of order $m\times n$, and $B$ is a matrix of order $n \times m$. So $AB$ is a square matrix and $\det(AB)$ therefore, exists.

By $\det$ properties:

$$\det(AB)=\det(A)\cdot \det(B)$$

But $\det A$ and $\det B$ cannot exist, as $A, B$ are not square matrixes.

How can it be?

Thank you.

Comment: "By det properties: detAB=detA*detB" - true only if $A$ and $B$ are square.

Comment: So every time i use this rule i must prove or assume that A,B are square, thanks

Comment: Yes, the rule only holds in that case.

Comment: What is the determinant of a non-square matrix?

Comment: It is undefined?

Comment: @ElliotG , I hope this helps, http://static.bsu.az/w24/pp.163-175.pdf

Comment: I'm sure that is not what Alon is looking for in an intro linear algebra class.

Comment: So undefined on my level?

Answer (score 1):

The [Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) is one generalization of the multiplicative property of determinants to when $A$ and $B$ are not square but whose product is square. If $A$ and $B$ are matrices with dimensions $m \times n$ and $n \times m$, where $m \le n$, the formula states that:

$$\det(AB) = \sum_{1 \le i_1 < i_2 < \ldots < i_m \le n} \det{A_{[i_1,\ldots, i_m]}}\det{B_{[i_1,\ldots,i_m]}}$$

where $A_{[i_1,\ldots,i_m]}$ is the $m \times m$ matrix formed by taking the $i_1$th through $i_m$th columns of $A$ and $B_{[i_1, \ldots, i_m]}$ is the $m \times m$ matrix formed by taking the $i_1$th through $i_m$th rows of $B$.

In the case where $m = n$, there's only one possible choice of indices $i_1 = 1, i_2 = 2, \ldots, i_m = m$ and we recover the standard multiplicative property of square matrices.

Comment: I didnt ubderstand the formula, but mybe it will help  someone else, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The definition is as follows:

**"The determinant of a matrix product of square matrices equals the product of their determinants"** (Wikipedia)

We must have $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$.

We cannot have $A$ as $n\times n$ and $B$ as $s\times s$, because then their product is not defined.

You are assuming that just because the product is square, that the initial two matricies are square. This is **not true**, as you have shown in your example.

Comment: Ok, i understand, thanks